# WCF Server get WCF client version automatically

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I was created one WCF service some months ago and now I am going to upgrade that WCF service like adding new data member and remove some data member and perform the some extra task in the upgraded service for the only new WCF client not for the old client.

How can I know that the service is called by the new WCF client or the old WCF client ?

**Service**

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{
    void Insert(WCFClientInfo wcfClientInfo, Employee employee);
}
```

Implementaion

```
public class Service1 : IService1
{
    public void Insert(WCFClientInfo wcfClientInfo, Employee employee)
    {
        // My Task
    }
}
```

Employee

```
[DataContract]
public class Employee
{
    [DataMember(Order = 1)]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Order = 2)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Order = 3)]
    public string MobileNo { get; set; }
}
```

WCFClientInfo

```
[DataContract]
public class WCFClientInfo
{
    [DataMember]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

Now I am adding the new field in the `Employee` data contract is `EMail`.

Employee

```
[DataContract]
public class Employee
{
    [DataMember(Order = 1)]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Order = 2)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Order = 3)]
    public string MobileNo { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Order = 4)]
    public string EMail { get; set; }
}
```

So now I want to know the WCF client user is old or new, so for that I add one more field `ClientVersion` in the `WCFClientInfo`.

WCFClientInfo

```
[DataContract]
public class WCFClientInfo
{
    [DataMember]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string ClientVersion { get; set; }
    // It must be filled automatically by the WCF client 
    // Means no need to provide by the client manually. 
}
```

New Implementation:

```
public void Insert(WCFClientInfo wcfClientInfo, Employee employee)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(wcfClientInfo.ClientVersion) ||
        wcfClientInfo.ClientVersion == "V1.0.0")
    {
        SendSMS(employee.MobileNo);
    }
    else if (wcfClientInfo.ClientVersion == "V2.0.0")
    {
        SendEMail(employee.EMail);
    }
}
```

So previously there is no `ClientVersion` field in the `WCFClientInfo` class, but in the upgraded WCF Service there will ve the `ClientVersion` field.

So now problem is I want the WCF Client Version in the `ClientVersion` class automatically and there will be need to pass it manually be the client.

Can I made the changes in the WSDL file of the client like add some constant version field and that constant version field will be send automatically when client made the request to the server ?

Answer (score 0):

You are not controlling old clients. They already have old WSDL and will send messages without any new fields.

In general adding new fields to your contract is OK - they will just get `null` values when you receive the message.

However, removing fields is dangerous, because WCF infrastructure will fail to deserialize incoming messages from old clients.

Typical approach to be used when you want to change contract significantly is to introduce versioning in the endpoint URLs.

E.g. old URL might be `http://yourhost.com/YourService/` and the new one will be `http://yourhost.com/YourServiceV2/` where new contract can be used.